# How to prove that $A-(B\cap C)=(A-B)\cup (A-C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove that $A-(B\cap C)=(A-B)\cup (A-C)$.

I have tried to prove it but I can't get precious proof. I am grateful if anyone give correct proof.

Comment: I always forget to first-close, then-edit when these questions come up. That way I lose my mjolnir abilities when I change the tags... :-)

Comment: Since x$\in x$\in A-(B\cap C),x\in A but not belongs to B intersection C. I.e x not belongs to B and not belongs to C but belongs to A.and now I'm stoped

Comment: That's not correct. $x\in A-(B\cap C)$ means that $x$ belongs to $A$, but not to both $B$ and $C$. So either $A$ and not $B$ and not $C$, or $A$ and _one_ of $B$ and $C$, but not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ordinary language, that's pretty obvious:
an element in $A-B\cap C$ is an element which is in $A$, but not in *both* $B$ and $C$, that is, an element in $A$, but not in  $B$ *or* not in $C$ (and always in $A$, of course).

Comment: But I need a formal proof not logical proof ...can you explain me sir please

Comment: I said in ordinary language  *exactly* what the other answer says with formulae. E. g., the first sentence says $\;A-B\cap C=A\cap(B\cap C)^{\mathrm c}$, the second that the latter is $\;A\cap(B^{\mathrm c}\cup C\mathrm C^{\mathrm c})$, &c.

Comment: Could u explain it sir?

Comment: I'd love to, but  I don't see very well  what there's to explain, once you that $(B\cap C)^{\mathrm c}$ denotes the elements which are not in $B\cap C$, i.e. which are not in ($B$ and $C$) (1st sentence), and so on? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following basic properties about sets:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
(1) & X\setminus Y=X\cap Y^c\\
(2) & (X\cup Y)^c=X^c\cap Y^c\ \text{(De morgan rules)} \\
(3) & X\cap(Y\cup Z)=(X\cap Y)\cup(X\cap Z)\ \text{(distributive law)}\\
\end{array}
$$
Now
$$
\begin{split}
A\setminus(B\cap C) 
&=A\cap(B\cap C)^c\\
&=A\cap(B^c\cup C^c)\\
&=(A\cap B^c)\cup(A\cap C^c)\\
&=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\setminus C)
\end{split}
$$
as required.